# How to do DB update in a single query in django when using an IF condition?

Tags: django

I have the following code -

```
 testcase = Table1.objects.filter(ID=id,serialno ='1234', condition='False').exists()
 if not testcase:
     c = Table1.objects.filter(ID=id,serialno ='1234').select_for_update().update(condition='True')
```

Here, I am querying the same DB twice. Is there any way where I can do the filter exists and update in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering doesn't send a query.
I agree with the answer above, but if you want a correction for you code, then this would be correct:

```
testcase = Table1.objects.filter(ID=id,serialno ='1234')
if not testcase.filter(condition='False'):
     c = testcase.select_for_update().update(condition='True')
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I will update my code. Also, will something like this work? testcase = Table1.objects.filter(Id=id, serialno='1234').select_for_update().update(condition=When(~Q(condition='False'), then=Value('True')))

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `update` method with your filter query.

```
Table1.objects.filter(ID=id,serialno ='1234', condition='False').update(condition=True)
```